Plasma (KDE) missing gesture
I have just installed Plasma 6.1 (plasma-meta) on my Arch Linux system
but none of the gestures (touchpad) sponsored is available (three or four fingers).
What am I missing?
PS: I already have GNOME 46 installed and gestures work flawlessly
